# Ubuntu for old pc

Tags: 12.04, 11.10

Ubuntu Admins, please listen to me.. I have a proposal.

Ubuntu is a very, very good OS. better than windows, but, my pc is very slower, why do not create a Ubuntu for old pc's?

would be a grand idea. Good job guys. And thanks!

Comment: @Takkat he's asking to create a Ubuntu for old PC. He's not interested in that.

Comment: @searchfgold6789 the same, he's asking the we create a Ubuntu for old pc's, he's not interested in that.

Comment: @Braiam: so what do you suggest we do?

Comment: @Takkat not close it as duplicated for starters ;) Then close it as feature request (bug report).

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for Xubuntu. From the distro's front page:

> Xubuntu is perfect for those who want the most out of their desktops, laptops and netbooks with a modern look and enough features for efficient, daily usage. **It works well on older hardware too.**

I've used it on some old PCs at my workplace and it has actually become my preferred ubuntu flavor